# UIScrollView- How far is it scrolled?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm using an UIScrollView and I have an image that indicates to the user that there is more content that they can scroll through vertically. I would like this image to be hidden when the scrollview is all the way at the bottom. Is there a way to do this? Would I have to subclass UIScrollView and make my own?

Comment: Are you on iPhone and using `UIScrollView`, or not on iPhone and using `NSScrollView`? This question's tags need cleaning up.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I have fixed this.

Comment: Be aware, this may be a violation of Apple's HIG. After all, the built-in `UIScrollView` does not show its thumbs unless the user is scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your scroll view's delegate should repsond to [scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:) and use that to check where you are

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  // Get some details about the view
  CGSize size = [scrollView frame].size;
  CGPoint offset = [scrollView contentOffset];
  CGSize contentSize = [scrollView contentSize];

  // Are we at the bottom?
  if (-offset.y + size.height <= contentSize.height)
    NSLog(@"bottom");
  else
    NSLog(@"not bottom");
}
```

NB The if statement was done in my head so it might be the wrong way round ;)